# Using parameters from shell script in my Java code

Tags: java, shell

I have to write two scripts, one to compile my code and another one to run it. I manage to compile the code with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
javac SimilaridadeP.java
```

And I was able to run it using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
java SimilaridadeP
```

The problem is that I need to execute my second shell script following this command:

```
./execute.sh input output
```

Where input and output are the names of the files that I am going to use in my Java code. The problem that I am facing right now is that I don't know how I can use these both names in my Java code.

So far I managed to get both names using this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
in=$1
out=$2
java SimilaridadeP
```

But since "SimilaridadeP" is the name of my java file and it can't be called like a method with parameters I am kind of lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your java code is already reading the command-line parameters, it's just a matter of changing the bash this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
java SimilaridadeP "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! So what I have in my Java class is something similar to scanf in C. My main doubt is in how do I read the command line parameters.

Comment: I did not add any validation, but here is the basics: public static void main(String[] args) { String parm1 = args[0]; String parm2 = args[1]; ..... }

Answer (score 2):

This works with arbitrary number of arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
java SimilaridadeP "$@"
```